# Different ways of how can assembly store parameters?

Tags: assembly, nasm, calling-convention, function-parameter

I am novice in Assembly(NASM),I have questions.I have read that we can store parameters in 6 register, but I also have read that we can store parameters in ebp+value.
Can we store parameters of function either in register or ebp+value?

If it's correct, can we save our local variable in register as well as in ebp-value?

Thank you

Comment: Consult the appropriate calling convention documentation. You can also make up your own parameter passing as long as caller and callee agree on where the parameters are. The cpu doesn't care. Note that you don't need to use `ebp` even if you use the stack.

Comment: assembly language gives you the freedom to do whatever you within the rules of the instruction set.  Unless you are interfacing with a high level language (C, etc) then you need to conform to the calling convention for that compiler (assume compiler specific and not target specific).

Comment: You might be mixing up 32-bit and 64-bit calling conventions.  In 32-bit code under the SysV calling conventions (used on Linux, etc), parameters are passed on the stack and are commonly accessed via offsets to `ebp`.  In 64-bit SysV code, the first six parameters are passed in registers.  When you read things about assembly language, be sure to check which architecture, mode, and operating system they are talking about; statements true for one combination may not transfer to others.